# How to analyze a USB device of having possibly malicious capabilities?

Tags: reverse-engineering, usb, badusb, hid-analysis, usb-analysis

So I recently ordered a chinese external USB card and I would like to find out whether it has some hidden functionality, which might become malicious. It has buttons integrated in it so Linux using `libusb -vv` displays it of having HID capabilities, which already alerted me since it could be used to inject keystrokes.

- How do I go on continuing my analysis?
- Can I dump more information about its capabilities using libusb?
- How do I dump its firmware for reverse engineering purposes? According to [this] that's only possible with a JTAG/UART connection?
- Is there something like
  Wireshark but for USB?

Bonus points if you also add some libusb example code.

Comment: *"Is there something like Wireshark but for USB?"* - why use "something like" if you could use Wireshark directly - https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB

Comment: @SteffenUllrich ooh, I was not aware of this functionality, thank you!